# Why is my output from pipe in C still producing garbage data?

Tags: c, memory, pipe

What I'm trying to do is run a program and return the entire output and print the results one line at a time.

When I executed the program using a.out as a parameter, everything works so far until I start attempting to read more data from the pipe. I received the following as results:

```
Line 0: 
Line 1: 
MCS-51 Family Macro Assembler ASEM-51 V1.3
Line 2:                                   

Line 3: 
a.out(1): illegal character
Line 4:                    
a.out(2): illegal character
Line 5:                    
a.out(3): illegal character
Line 6:                    
a.out(4): illegal character
Line 7:                    
a.out(5): illegal character
Line 8:                    
a.out(5): no END statement found
Line 9:                         

Line 10: 
             6 errors detected
Line 11:                      
Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
Line 12:
Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set      correctly.
Line 13:
err:systray:initialize_systray Could not create tray window
Line 14:
```

However, lines 11 through 14 shouldn't appear at all since the remote program that I executed finished after printing the contents of line 10.

Do ignore the illegal character statements. That is intended because I'm making a program that executes a third party assembler and I'm passing invalid source code in.

I attempted to add a character code 255 to output back from the child to the parent but I'm unable to receive it in the parent, however if I attempt to execute a non-existing file on my system, I'm able to send the word "ERROR" back to the parent and retrieve it in the parent.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here but I'm trying to find a way to determine when to stop attempting to read further data to the point where the parent receives garbage from the child instead of the true output.

How do I fix this?

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

char line[100][512];
int numlines=0;

int run(char* dir,char* mainapp,char *par1,char *par2){
int pf[2]; //pf = PipeFields
pipe(pf);
if (fork()==0){
  //CHILD START
  //cmdline = commandline to program = directory (dir) + / + main app name + padded nulls
  char cmdline[10000];
  memset(cmdline,0,10000);
  strcat(cmdline,dir);
  strcat(cmdline,"/");
  strcat(cmdline,mainapp);
  char *args[5]={cmdline,par1,par2,NULL}; //arguments to program
  close(pf[0]);
  //redirect all output streams to same place
  dup2(pf[1],1);
  dup2(pf[1],2);
  //return error as part of output if program can't execute
  if (execve(cmdline,args,NULL) < 0){write(pf[1],"ERROR",5);}
  //return ascii character as last byte to output back to caller
  write(pf[1],(unsigned char*)255,1);
  close(pf[1]);
  //CHILD END
}else{
  //b = buffer
  memset(line,0,51200); //clear all lines of output
  char b[102400];
  memset(b,0,102400); //clear temporary buffer
  char *b2=b; //make reference to buffer for strcat
  char incoming[10001]; //incoming buffer of 10000 bytes of data plus null
  close(pf[1]); //don't need to write to child. close pipe.
  long hasdata=0,sz=0;
  while((sz=read(pf[0],incoming,sizeof(incoming)-1)) > 0){
//execute this while incoming pipe has between 1 and 10000 bytes of data
printf(">>> %ld >> %s\n",sz,incoming); // <-- show output for debugging
incoming[sz]='\0'; //add null to end of incoming data so strcat can work
strcat(b2,incoming); //add incoming data to main buffer
hasdata=1; //we have data
//see if incoming data contains magic character code 255 as a byte
if (strchr(incoming,255)){
  //but this never gets executed? what's going on???
  printf("BREAKKKKK");
  break;
}
  }
  //if theres data then convert it into lines
  if (hasdata==1){
numlines=0; //reset number of lines
char *bp=b; //make reference to data
char *thisln=line[0]; //make reference to line
while(*bp){
  if(*bp=='\n'){ //if theres a new line,...
    numlines++; //increment counter...
    if (numlines > 100){break;} //and exit if theres too many lines
    thisln=line[numlines]; //make reference to next line
  }
  *thisln=*bp; //transfer bytes 1 by 1 to appropiate areas
  bp++;        //and increment pointer
  thisln++;
}
  }
  close(pf[0]);
  }
return 0;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
  int thisline;
  //get 2 arguments
  if (argc < 2){printf("Filename required\n");return -1;}
  //make sure argument is valid file
  if (access(argv[1],R_OK) < 0){printf("File not found: %s\n",argv[1]);return -2;}
  //run app
  run("/usr/bin","wine","/DOS/8051asm/asemw.exe",argv[1]);
  //print results line by line
  for (thisline=0;thisline<=numlines;thisline++){
printf("Line %d: %s\n",thisline,line[thisline]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a workaround, you might try setting and exporting `WINEDEBUG=err-systray`, which will stop wine from outputting systray errors to fd 2.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line  2) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'. unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Never use tabs for indenting,  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that will be easily visible, even with variable width fonts,.

Comment: the `fork()` function actually returns three different indications : >0 when parent, ==0 when child, and <0 when an error occurs.  The code needs to check for all three conditions (a switch statement works very well for this.

Comment: the function: `execvp()` only returns when an error occurs.  So anything after the call to `execvp()` should only be calling `perror();` followed by `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: the child process should only be terminated by `exit()` or `_exit()` NOT allowed to fall (after the end of the if/then/else) to more code that should only be executed by the parent.

Comment: note: a pipe is a one way street, so do not try to pass data in both directions

Comment: the parent, after determining that it is the parent,  should (eventually) call `waitpid()` to wait for the child to exit

Comment: when any error occurs, the code should output the error message to stderr.  When the error is not from a system function, then it is (usually) best to use `fprintf( stderr, "formatstring", parameters );`

Comment: in the call to `access()` the reason for failure could be the file could not be read, or could be the file does not exist where it is expected to exist.  so the error message is not necessarily correct.  You should use a mode of `F_OK` if all that you are interested in is if the file exists.

Comment: this line: ` char cmdline[10000];`  is allocating 10,000 bytes from the stack.  It 'probably' will work, but is a bad idea to allocate such large chunks of the stack.

Comment: this line: `write(pf[1],(unsigned char*)255,1);` is trying to write one byte to the pipe, where that byte is located as address `255`.   This is very likely to result in a seg fault event as your program 'probably' does not have permission to read from address 255.

Comment: follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Answer (score 0):

the following code should do what you want.

Note: when 'wine' is not available, will output:

`execve failed: No such file or directory`

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define MAX_LINES    (512)
#define MAX_LINE_LEN (100)

void run(char* mainapp, char *par1, char *par2)
{
    int pf[2]; //pf = PipeFields
    if( pipe(pf) )
    { // then pipe() failed
        perror( "pipe failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if( 0 == pid )
    { // child

        //CHILD START
        char *args[]={ mainapp, par1, par2, NULL}; //arguments to program

        close( pf[0] ); // close child output end of pipe
        //redirect all output streams to pipe
        dup2(pf[1],1);
        dup2(pf[1],2);
        close(pf[1]);

        //return error as part of output if program can't execute
        execve(mainapp, args, NULL); // should never return
        perror( "execve failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    } // end child

    else if (-1 == pid )
    { // error occurred
        perror( "fork failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    } // end fork() error handling

    else
    { // parent
        close( pf[1] ); // close input end of pipe
        size_t thisline;
        char line[ MAX_LINES ][ MAX_LINE_LEN ];
        size_t lineNum=0;
        size_t charNum=0;
        int status;

        memset(line, '\0', MAX_LINES*MAX_LINE_LEN); //clear all lines of output


        while((read(pf[0], &line[lineNum][charNum], 1)) > 0)
        {
            if( '\n' == line[lineNum][charNum] )
            { // then step to next line
                // terminate string
                //charNum++;
                //line[lineNum][charNum] = '\0';
                // init for next line
                lineNum++;
                charNum = 0;
            }

            else
            {
                // step to next char
                charNum++;
            }

            if( charNum >= MAX_LINE_LEN )
            {
                printf( "input line too long -- exiting\n" );
                printf( "%s\n", line[lineNum] );
                wait( &status );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            if( lineNum >= MAX_LINES )
            {
                printf( "more than %ul lines in file -- exiting\n", MAX_LINES );
                wait( &status );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }   
        }
        close( pf[0] ); // close output end of pipe

        //printf( "%lu\n", lineNum); // for testing
        if( strncmp( line[0], "execve", strlen("execve") ) == 0 )
        {
             printf("%s\n", line[thisline]);
        }

        else 
        { // then some data to output
            //print results line by line
            for (thisline=0; thisline<lineNum; thisline++)
            {
                printf("Line %lu: %s\n", thisline, line[thisline]);
            }
        }
    }  // end parent
} // end function: run


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <Filename>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    //make sure argument is valid file
    if (access(argv[1],F_OK) < 0)
    {
        perror( "file not found" );
        fprintf( stderr, "Missing file is: %s\n",argv[1]);
        return -2;
    }

    else
    { 
        //run app
        run("/usr/bin/wine", "/DOS/8051asm/asemw.exe", argv[1]);
    }
}
```